# solving $\int \frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a}-c_2}}$

Tags: integration

I need to solve the integral

$\int \frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a}-c_2}}$

. Here, c$_1$ and c$_2$ are unknown constants.

I tried to solve it. I guess this can be solved using some trigonometric substitution, but I am not understanding exactly what to substitute. I tried substituting a = cos$^2$ $\theta$, but couldn't solve it. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

(Note: Mathematica may give direct answer, but I need to solve it by hand and know the intermediate steps)

Comment: What are the restrictions on $c_1,c_2$? The substitution changes drastically depending on what values they take on.

Comment: Rule of thumb: when there's a square root of a sum or difference, leverage Pythagoras. For example, if $c_1,\,c_2>0$ you can try $a=\frac{c_1}{c_2}\sin^2\theta$ so the square root is of $c_2\cot^2\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

Hoping that you do not mind, I changed the notations
$$I=\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{\frac a x-b}}$$
$$x=\frac{a}{b \left(t^2+1\right)}\quad \implies \quad I=-\frac{2 a}{b^{3/2}}\int \frac{dt}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}$$ which is not difficult (one integration by parts).

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=\int \frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a}-c_2}}$

Put, $a=\frac{c_1}{c_2} sin^2\theta $.

Then, $da=\frac{c_1}{c_2} 2sin\theta$ $cos\theta$  $d\theta $

Then,
$I=\int \frac {\frac{c_1}{c_2} 2 sin\theta cos\theta d\theta }{\sqrt{c_2 cosec^2 \theta -c_2}}$

$=\int \frac {\frac{c_1}{c_2} 2 sin\theta cos\theta d\theta }{\sqrt{c_2} cot \theta}$

$=\int \frac {c_1 2 sin\theta cos\theta d\theta }{{c_2}^\frac32 \frac{cos \theta}{sin\theta}}$

$=\int \frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32} 2sin^2\theta  d\theta  $

$=\frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}\int  2sin^2\theta  d\theta  $

$=\frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}\int  (1-cos2\theta)  d\theta  $

$=\frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}(\theta-\frac{sin2\theta}2) +c $

$=\frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}(\theta-sin\theta cos\theta) +c $

$=\frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}(sin^{-1}(\sqrt \frac{c_2a}{c_1})-\sqrt \frac{c_2a}{c_1}.\sqrt {1-\frac{c_2a}{c_1}} \big)+c $

$=\frac {c_1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}\big(sin^{-1}(\sqrt \frac{c_2a}{c_1}))-\frac {1 }{{c_2}^\frac32}\sqrt {c_2a}.\sqrt {c_1-c_2a} +c $

where $c$ is an integrating constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{d a}{\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a}-c_2}}=\int \frac{\sqrt{a} d a}{\sqrt{c_1-a c_2}} \\
= & \sqrt{c_2} \int \frac{\sqrt{a} d a}{\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{c_2}-a}} \\
= & \frac{2} {3}\sqrt{c_2} \int \frac{d\left(a^{3 / 2}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{c_2}-\left(a^{3 / 2}\right)^{2 / 3}}}
\end{aligned}
$$

This can be expressed in the following form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{d t}{\sqrt{k-t^{2 / 3}}}=\int \frac{t^{-1 / 3} d t}{t^{-1 / 3} \sqrt{k-t^{2 / 3}}}=\frac{3}{2} \int \frac{d\left(t^{2 / 3}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{t^{2 / 3}}-1}} \\
& =\frac{3}{2}\left[t^{2 / 3}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{t^{2 / 3}}-1}\right)-a \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t^{2 / 3}}-1}\right)\right]+c \\
& \text {applying this in our intial we get: }
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\\
= & \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{c_2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left[a\left(-\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a c_2}}-1\right)-a \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a c_2}-1}\right)\right. \\
= & \sqrt{c_2}\left[a\left(-\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a c_2}-1}\right)-a \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a c_2}-1}\right)\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$